# Minikube Synthetic Ethernet Port

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod, spinnaker

I am trying to start Minikube with the following command:

```
Command:minikube start --vm-driver hyperv
```

It shows the below error:

> Error:'minikube' Synthetic Ethernet Port (Instance ID
> DAFC6CDF-E16C-42D4-920B-3C180547A0A6): Failed to Power on with Error
> 'Attempt to access invalid address.' (0x800701E7). (Virtual machine ID
> AB87A24C-7B7E-41CA-B63D-A420FFCC508F) 'minikube' No available MAC
> address for "Network Adapter".

Comment: Can you try this

minikube start --driver=<driver_name>

Comment: it's working,but always my minikube apiServer and kubelet is in stopped status.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: yes.it's shows::::: reflector.go:382] k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:135: Failed to watch *v1.Endpoints: Get https://control-plane.minikube.internal:8443/api/v1/endpoints?allowWatchBookmarks=true&labelSelector=%21service.kubernetes.io%2Fheadless%2C%21service.kubernetes.io%2Fservice-proxy-name&resourceVersion=6384&timeout=7m10s&timeoutSeconds=430&watch=true: dial tcp 192.168.1.101:8443: connect: connection refused

Comment: Please, share more information about your setup. Are you running it on you local machine? Windows or Linux? Give as much information as you can.

Comment: local machine.windows 10.minikube version: v1.11.0 minikube Assigned Memory 4096 MB.virtual processors:4

Comment: try installing virtualbox and running with virtual box instead of hyperv...